# mysql database SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database

im getting error from this code
i don't how to figure it out

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    include "auth.php";
    if(isset($_GET["getlist"]))
    {
        $uid=$_GET["getlist"];
        
        $sql="SELECT * FROM devices WHERE brand_id=:uid ORDER BY id ASC";
        $query=$db->query($sql);
        $devices=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    }
?>
```

Comment: the `query` method doesn't handle prepared statements, so `:uid` is invalid

Comment: how can solve it ? its a number

Comment: check the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

done it by @lawrence-cherone helping

here is the answer

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    include "auth.php";
    if(isset($_GET["getlist"]))
    {
        
        try {
            $uid=(int)$_GET["getlist"];
            $sql=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE brand_id = :uid ORDER BY id ASC");
            $sql->execute([':uid' => $uid]);
            $devices = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What was the cause ?